# How to aggregate data in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, database, csv, date, aggregate

I have a csv file written in this format:

```
timestamp,user_holding
07/12/2018 00:45,23
07/12/2018 01:45,48
07/12/2018 06:45,67
08/12/2018 07:45,12
08/12/2018 13:45,35
08/12/2018 18:45,67
.....
```

What i need to do is to aggregate the user_holding per day so that I have:

```
timestamp,user_holding
07/12/2018,138
08/12/2018,114
....
```

I have to use python to to that because I need to do it for a lot of files,
is there a fast way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: see: 
[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
[agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

Comment: *"is there a fast way to do that"* - Yes, pasting your task in stack overflow and letting someone else work for you is a super fast way of doing that. Well done.

Comment: Have you already tried anything? You can load the csv data into a DataFrame and then use a groupby to sum all th user holdings for each date.

Answer (score -2):

Use regex. First remove those commas. Then add the commas where u need them to be.